# Lenovo T410 Trackpad Issues

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, thinkpad

I recently bought a used Lenovo T410 specifically to try Ubuntu but I'm having really frustrating problems with the trackpad. It seems to randomly lose the ability to click with any of the buttons or from tapping. I have only been able to resolve this by restarting but it happens so frequently that it has made for a very frustrating experience!

If anyone can offer any advice I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your response. I subsequently found the problem only seemed to happen when waking from suspend. Also the 'Trackpoint' seems to be part of the problem (the red pointer device in the middle of the keyboard.

To cut a long story short I disabled the trackpoint in the BIOS and all seems well now! For those with a similar level of ignorance to me you can enter the BIOS by holding <kbd>F12</kbd> when you see the thinkpad splash screen at start up.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jamesf/lenovofixes
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install psmouse-suspend-modules
```